# How to create method dependencies for argument?

Tags: android, kotlin, class, methods, dependencies

i was building a navigation app and facing this issue.

[image]

Comment: Use a lowercase `d` in "dependencies". Groovy and Kotlin function names always start with a lowercase letter by convention.

Answer (score 1):

**Use a lowercase d in "[dependencies](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#groovy)".**

```
dependencies {
        def nav_version = "2.5.2"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
    }
```